# TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [timedelta64[D]]

Tags: python, datetime

So I am trying to calculate the duration between two days but I just want the number of days instead of minutes and seconds for the duration. The code I am using is the following:

```
df['duration']=df['deadline'].sub(df['created_at'].astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

However, this gives me sth like : 35 days 12:42:40. But I don't want the "days 12:42:40." Instead, I want to extract the 35 as an interger. So I tried to replace the datetime64[D] with [timedelta64[D], which gave me the TypeError. Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic and easiest way to solve this problem is to subtract the two series from one another and then access the [datetime accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) on the series to retrieve the days.

Here is a quick example.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'deadline': pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-03-05', periods=5),
    'created_date': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-9', periods=5)
})

df['duration'] = (df.deadline - df.created_date).dt.days
```